# jQuery selector question. Select all nodes that do NOT START with (string)

Tags: jquery

Trying to assemble a rather complex jQuery selector here, and having trouble.

Essentially, I'm trying to grab all anchors that that 1) do not have a "rel" of "facebox", <strike>and</strike> **OR** 2) do not have an "href" that begins with "mailto".

This is what I've been trying to do:

```
$('a[rel!=facebox], a[href!^="mailto"]')
```

Small variations of this don't seem to work. Is there some better way of going about this?

These selectors seem to work individually, but not when sitting consecutively in the same selector:

```
$('a:not([rel=facebox]), a:not([href^=mailto])')
```

**Final solution:** We have a winner!

```
$('a:not([rel=facebox],[href^=mailto])')
```

Comment: Curiously, $('a:not([rel=facebox]') and $('a:not([href^=mailto]') work fine, but not both separated by a comma.

Comment: That's because the commas adds the object after it to the jQuery-object, effectivly selecing all but the nodes that has both rel=facebox and href with mailto.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You want the [:not selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector)

```
$("a:not([rel=facebox],[href^=mailto])");
```

EDIT: I stole your answer for correctness

Comment: There we go- now I feel better about selecting it as the accepted answer. You were right about the :not selector originally, but I hadn't phrased my question correctly.

Comment: Question about this answer:  Why is the ^= needed?  Doesn't that mean "not equals" while you meanwhile have already written ":not?"

Answer (score 3):

Alright Mr. Jeremy Ricketts. Jquery has messed up your head. You are trying to chain selector logic...kind of like how jQuery chains methods. In your second selector (`a[href!^="mailto"]`) you are trying to say...NOT things that contain THIS attribute. What you are saying is "Search for all things that are not mailto" and "Search for all things that contain mailto". It's like light filters...if you filter red light...and throw a yellow light filter on top...you are not filtering for orange light...you just filtered out EVERYTHING (sorry for the stretch of an analogy). So what you are trying to do is use the pseudo selector :not.

Like this - `$(a:not([href^=mailto:])).whateverJqueryMethodYouWant();`

EDIT:
Well now that you have spec'd out the question properly...you can do it like this - `$(a:not([href^=mailto:] , [rel=facebox])).whateverJqueryFunctionYouWant();`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
$("a:not([rel='facebox'],[href^='mailto'])");
```