# how to get element that does not start with particular name

Tags: jquery

```
$('[name^="field_"][type="checkbox"]');
```

Above gives the list of checkboxes with name that start with `field_`.

How can I get all the checkboxes that does not start with `field_`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check this, see if can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604344/jquery-selector-question-select-all-nodes-that-do-not-start-with-string

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('[type="checkbox"]:not([name^="field_"])');
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets say we want all "a" tags which do not have class starting with "comment". This is what you will call

```
$('a:not([class^="comment"])')
```

Comment: May be worth pointing out that if you do this for class names it literally means the start of the class attribute. If there's another class name in the class attribute beginning with 'comment' it will not get picked up by the :not clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to select based on custom rules:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
    return this.name.substring(0, 6) !== "field_";
});
```