# jquery selector for attributes that does not begin with a string

Tags: jquery, selector

Selector starting with `[name^="value"]` selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

Is there a negative of this like so:

```
[name!^="value"]
```

which selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value NOT beginning with a given string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get element that does not start with particular name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966350/how-to-get-element-that-does-not-start-with-particular-name)

Answer (score 28):

```
$("div").not('[name^="value"]');
```

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps you can use the `:not()` selector: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
$('input').not('[name^="value"]')...;
```

Here's a jsfiddle using `.not()`: http://jsfiddle.net/hNhgf/