# Struggling with jQuery conditional selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now.

I want to select all anchor links that begin with the attribute 'http: //localhost' and exclude all links that contain 'wp-admin' in them.

I can select all links that begin with 'http: //localhost' with this:

```
$internalLinks = $("a[href^='http://localhost']")
```

This is what I have so far for excluding the 'wp-admin' links, but it doesn't work:

```
$internalLinks = $("a:not[href*='wp-admin']a[href^='http://localhost']"),
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You've nearly got it. The selector you're looking for is this:

```
a[href^='http://localhost']:not([href*='wp-admin'])
```

The two mistakes you made were 1) repeating the tag name (`a`) and 2) forgetting the parentheses for the `:not()` selector.

Comment: ahh!!! that's it! 4 hours of my eyes bleeding. thank you so much!

I was simply following what was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687131/jquery-select-by-attribute-using-and-and-or-operator

I couldn't find any documentation on how to properly order it. is there any or is it a thing you just know over time?

Comment: @Kenny: Order usually doesn't matter, except the tag name must come first.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to select all anchor links that begin with the attribute `http:/localhost` and exclude all links that contain 'wp-admin' in them.

Given the relative complexity of your condition I would consider using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    // starts with 'http://localhost' and does not contain 'wp-admin'
    return this.href.indexOf('http://localhost') == 0 && 
       this.href.indexOf('wp-admin') == -1;
});
```

Doing everything in a single expression doesn't mean you avoid evaluating all anchors on the page, so you might as well make it easier on yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $internalLinks = $("a[href^='http://localhost']").not("a[href*='wp-admin']");
```

**Example**

http://jsbin.com/burobako/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

use somthing like this

```
$("a:not([href^=wp-admin])");
```

and see this link

[jQuery selector question. Select all nodes that do NOT START with (string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604344/jquery-selector-question-select-all-nodes-that-do-not-start-with-string)